# How to use CSS transition for existing list items to make room for new ones?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Suppose I have the following HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>AlwaysAtTheEnd</li>
</ul>
```

After list item 3, I will be inserting a list item 4 using javascript. After that happens, the HTML will look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>AlwaysAtTheEnd</li>
</ul>
```

However, I want the "AlwaysAtTheEnd" item to smoothly slide down to make room for the new item rather than instantly pop down to make space.

I tried simply adding the following CSS, but it doesn't seem to affect anything:

```
li {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Fiddle here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/pcsj2mgb/

**EDIT:** Fixed fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/pcsj2mgb/1/

Comment: The javascript you have in the fiddle is indeed wrong. You're appending a child node to the second last item. It should be as hitesh below did: appending to the `parentNode` of the second last item. Altough it could just be `lastItem.parentNode.insertBefore(newItem, lastItem)`, skipping the use of `nextSibling` if you'd get the last item instead of the second last.

Comment: @Sevanteri Okay, I've made the change here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/pcsj2mgb/1/ but the animation still doesn't work.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is downvoted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can be done with CSS, <s>though you are going to need to define the final height of the `li` elements so you can animate **to** that height.</s>

And of course, you need to add the `newItem` class to the element you're appending, so the CSS affects it.

**Update**: No need to define a final height! Let's' just animate the `max-height`. Updated the snippet.

```js
add = function() {
  listItems = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  var lastItem = listItems[listItems.length - 1]
  var newItem = document.createElement('li');
  newItem.innerHTML = "4";

  newItem.classList.add("newItem");

  lastItem.parentNode.insertBefore(newItem, lastItem);
}
```

```css
.newItem {
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: grow 1s ease-in-out forwards;
  -webkit-animation: grow 1s ease-in-out forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes grow {
  to {
    max-height: 20px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes grow {
  to {
    max-height: 20px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>AlwaysAtTheEnd</li>
</ul>
<button onClick="add()">Add</button>
```

Comment: You realise that your 'AlwaysAtTheEnd` list-item isn't moving anywhere in your demo?

Comment: What browser are you using? On Firefox it works nicely.

Comment: Understood, and you have my empathy. Also, an up-vote; but I think 'empathy' is the key, here. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have change in your javascript code :

```
add = function(){
    var listItems = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    var secondLastItem = listItems[listItems.length - 2];
    var newItem = document.createElement('li');
    newItem.innerText = 4;

    // some pre defined css to new item
    newItem.style.height = '0px';
    newItem.style['opacity'] = '0';

    // This is change : because you are appending li into second last li, not in ul : so this function will insert li after last second item 
    secondLastItem.parentNode.insertBefore(newItem, secondLastItem.nextSibling);

    setTimeout(function(){
        // after append new item will get some css changes
        newItem.style.height = '18px';
        newItem.style['opacity'] = '1';
    },10)
```

}

you can see my fiddle link of this example : http://fiddle.jshell.net/13gg7kwf/

Comment: The `setTimeout` is not the best solution for this. It didn't even work for me with 10ms. I had to raise it up to 100ms and then it worked.

Comment: So I can't do this via pure CSS?

Answer (score -2):

Adding the CSS values via Javascript is a bit of a dirty hack.

I have found a way to achieve this by using a CSS only solution(  thanks to : 
http://christianheilmann.com/2013/09/19/quicky-fading-in-a-newly-created-element-using-css/).

Instead of using Transition you should use Animation.

You create a CSS class, and add it via JS, that triggers the animation right after the element is added to the DOM :

```
li.fade {
    -webkit-animation: fade 5s;
    animation: fade 5s;
    opacity: 1;
}
/* -fail- */
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
from {opacity: 0}
to {opacity: 1}
}@keyframes fade {
from {opacity: 0}
to {opacity: 1}
}
```

Complete solution :
http://jsfiddle.net/8wdk63ce/